# Gaming Questions of the Week #6

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Sample Questions:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second week's question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- Third week's question - [Does GLaDOS hate Atlas, the Blue Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20540/3015)

If you want to nominate either of the two sample questions for this week, post them as an answer. Feel free to nominate any questions (or answers) you feel are deserve it as well!

Answer (score 6):

I nominate this question!

[Do positive coordinate locations give more ore in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/do-positive-coordinate-locations-give-more-ore-in-minecraft)

Comment: Perhaps we can make a compilation of Minecraft posts this week? We've had a ton of great ones

Comment: would you be interested in writing a Question of the Week blog post about Minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

[How can I play Day of the Tentacle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/how-can-i-play-day-of-the-tentacle)

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why anyone would want that as well? ;P

Comment: The continued presence of ASCII art roguelikes on the site show that not everyone is concerned about graphics in their games.  And in terms of gameplay and script, this one is great.  So why shouldn't people be interested in how to play it on modern equipment?

Comment: I meant that you should explain that in a blog post ;-) "Forget graphics and learn to love 8-bit games"

Comment: I see.  Well, I'm already committed to an article for the last question of the week, so I can't take on this one myself. =)

Answer (score 0):

From chat

> Minecrafters: I need a Question of the Week overview of some of our Minecraft content, any takers?

- [How do level seeds work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/how-do-level-seeds-work)
- [What's the cause of the South/West Rule?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22467/whats-the-cause-of-the-south-west-rule)
- [What's the difference between the Fancy and Fast settings in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22241/whats-the-difference-between-the-fancy-and-fast-settings-in-minecraft)
- [Is it possible to create a portal larger than 2x3 to the Nether?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22202/is-it-possible-to-create-a-portal-larger-than-2x3-to-the-nether)
- [How far can redstone current travel?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22114/how-far-can-redstone-current-travel)